# 4-wire resistance measurement suitable range

Tags: electrical-engineering

First, the task is to measure surface resistivity of solar cells to monitor the surface degradation.

I am testing some measuring function and accuracy by putting a simple *31 kΩ* resistor in the circuit. Using Keithley2400, I obtained similar resistance reading with 2-wire sensing `keithley.write(":SYST:RSEN OFF")` *R = 38.34 kΩ*. However, when I turned on the 4-wire sensing `keithley.write(":SYST:RSEN ON")`, resistance reading was way off *R = 57.1 MΩ*. I then repeated the measuring process using manual approach (manually set the voltage source on Keithley and sense the resistance), and obtained the same off value using 4-wire sensing.

From my understanding: 4-wire is typically used when measuring resistance below *1 kilohm*. So, question: **Does 4-wire sensing introduce reading error when the measuring resistance is large?**

My guess:

1. is the voltage input too large (was set at -10 V - 10 V) which is not desirable for 4-wire sensing?
2. the resistor is too large which is not suitable for 4-wire sensing?

Comment: 4wire connection fixes error from R (or maybe Z) of wires supplying the excitation V or I. That should be negligible here. 30k resistive should be a fairly easy measurement.

Comment: My understanding is similar to PeteW. The additional wires are used to compensate for errors (e.g. temperature difference etc). For larger resistances, the effect of the error is negligible in relative terms, however, when resistances are smaller, the error becomes relatively greater and additionally you might change the dynamics of the circuit.

Comment: OK thanks guys. After two days testing I found there was a configuration error in Keithley itself which lead to the inconsistancy between 2 & 4 wire sensing. And yeh 4-wire does compensate the introduced errors from additional leads.